# Google Sheets API not triggering when run app on device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm making a simple app for Android using Cordova on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. When I run on Browser simulating a device, like LG G5, it works fine but when I run the Release Version on my phone nothing happens.

(I made the basic, that is read some lines and write)

When I run on Debug, showing some columns and rows correctly
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aBuS.jpg

What I got when run on Release mode or Build and install APK manully
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9t2q.jpg

I just paste the quickstart code from Google Sheets API Documentation

```
function initClient() {
                gapi.client.init({
                    apiKey: API_KEY,
                    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                    discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                    scope: SCOPES
                }).then(function () {
                    appendPre('API incializada');
                    // Listen for sign-in state changes.
                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
                    // Handle the initial sign-in state.
                    updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                    signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
                }, function (error) {
                    appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
                });
            }
```

I did not recive the error JSON and nothing happens, I already checked if the app have internet connection, the keystore properties are created and set.

Someone have the same issue? I tried everthing.